# Control Variables in RD design

Tags: treatment-effect, regression-discontinuity

There is a large concern about using control variables that are not predetermined (i.e. may be affected by a treatment), in DID and Matching approaches.

How is this in an RD approach after the newest advances? Should we hesitate to add controls that may be affected by the treatment? Take a pension reform as an example, with 60 as the age-cutoff. The variable "currently smoking" may be affected by the treatment. Is it better to not use this variable? If so, why? (mathematical explanation would be best)

Comment: Your question is rather unclear; are you asking whether to not include controls that are correlated with treatment?

Comment: I am asking whether, in an RD design, we should include a control variable that may be changed as a result of the treatment (e.g. "currently smoking" may be affected at the retirement threshold). If we see a jump in the variable "currently smoking", we would not include it. However, if we have no jump, it is unclear to me whether we should include it or not, and why. The reasoning of including it could be that we know smoking affects mental health.
I would like to have a mathematical explanation, if possible.